# Tweet a message with the '#' (hashtag)

Tags: html, url, twitter, tweets

I try to tweet a message on twitter with the "#". The problem is, that when I tweet for example:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=#some message">To Twitter</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=&#35;some message">To Twitter</a>
```

then the "some message" will be not displayed - everything after **#** or **#** will be deleted.

Exist there any way, how to append to message the hashtag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `%23`:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=%23some message">To Twitter</a>
```

---

`&#35;` is [HTML encode](http://jsfiddle.net/y2k26/), `%23` is [URL encode](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php).